# How to edit, delete and customize a stored response example in Postman?

Tags: postman

In [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com), I saved a response example when I send a request, but I can't delete or rename it. I don't see place to customize the response example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- Load the request(click on it on the left panel)

[image]

2- Click on the URL at the top panel to list all the responses saved for the given request

[image]

3- If you click on any of the saved responses, it will be loaded at the bottom part, to rename it you can just save it again with a different name and delete the previous one.

[image]

Source: [All responses saved for a request will be available whenever you load the request (above the request URL).](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/responses)

Comment: No. The top of that list only be response history. I need customize response example which saved and be named.

Comment: Once you click on the URL at the top you will be able to see all the responses saved for the given request. Please have a look at the pictures and give it a try again :)

Comment: sorry, I saw it

Answer (score 5):

This is for v6.0.10 :

1. click examples
2. hover on the list and you will see bucket icon
3. click that icon and your example is gone

[image]